# What is the most efficient pythonic way to iterate over several arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab, matrix

I am converting some matlab code into python and would like to know the best way to iterate over several numpy arrays. I included my solution below but would like to hear suggestions on how I can improve it? Thanks

Matlab--

```matlab
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        pT(i) = dC(i,j)*p(j) + pT(i);
    end
end
```

Python--

```py
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        pT[0][i] = np.dot(dC[i][j],p[0][j]) + pT[0][i]
```

`dC` is a 3x3 array, `p` and `pT` are 1x3 arrays.

Comment: if you are using `numpy`, you should avoid iteration as much as possible!

Comment: Can't that MATLAB be written as something like `pT = dC*p + pT`?

Answer (score 3):

This is just `p @ dC.transpose() + pT`, you don't actually need loops.

```
import numpy as np 

pT = np.array([1, 2, 3])
p  = np.array([4, 5, 6])
dC = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

pT = p @ dC.transpose() + pT    # [ 33  79 125]
```